# Wix Toolset - How do I add platforminstaller property to my .wixproj

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Environment:
Visual Studio 2019 WPF .Net Framework 4.8
Wix Toolset - latest version
Link to [article](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/14/working-hard-or-hardly-working/)

I'm trying to mark my components to be 64-bit and according to article below there are 2 "easy ways".

1. Use -arch on command line. I'm using Visual Studio that automatically runs candle.exe. Is there a way to add through Visual Studio?
2. Use InstallerPlatform property in .wixproj. I unload the .wixproj and then edit it but I have no idea where and how to specify this property.

[image]

Comment: It is not very neat, but unloading the WiX project `(Right click Wix project => "Unload Project")` and then right clicking the project (which now says "unavailable") and `"Edit [ProjetName].wixproj"` will give you the wixproj file raw (you can also edit it with a text editor by opening it). Now inject `"<InstallerPlatform>x64</InstallerPlatform>"` into the debug and release configurations and see what this does.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the -arch switch to compile using candle.exe and light.exe manually:"%WIX%bin\candle.exe" product.wxs -arch x64 -ext WixUIExtension >> Build.log
"%WIX%bin\light.exe" -out Test.msi product.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension >> Build.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something better than this (perhaps Chris Painter shows up - he is the apex build automation guy), but here goes with some pragmatic tweaks:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
  <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  <InstallerPlatform>x64</InstallerPlatform>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>Debug;</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
  <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  <InstallerPlatform>x64</InstallerPlatform>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

I am not sure if Votive (WiX component in Visual Studio) will preserve this value or if it might get removed as you work.

Hence using **`candle.exe`** and **`light.exe`** manually could be safer - I am not sure. I don't have this particular use-case right now:

```
"%WIX%bin\candle.exe" product.wxs -arch x64 -ext WixUIExtension >> Build.log 
"%WIX%bin\light.exe" -out Test.msi product.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension >> Build.log
```